# Is it possible to have a page master?

Tags: page

I have two types of page in my newspaper: one with a certain header that I only use once, and another that has a header that must repeat itself in all pages. Latex adds new pages automatically (when he needs to do so). Is it possible to set the new page in a specific format? (with specific graphics)?

P.S.
This is an example of code: in first page banner A, second page banner B and third and so on the same banner.

```
\documentclass[12pt,portrait]{article}
\usepackage[Italian]{babel}  %--setta regole lingua italiana
\usepackage[ddmmyyyy]{datetime} %--setta data formato IT

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e} %--per allineamento testo a dx, sx o giustificato
\usepackage{hyperref} %--- per i link
\usepackage{multicol} %------ per formattare pagine a più colonne
\usepackage{tcolorbox} %--- per le caselle di testo I pagina
\usepackage[percent]{overpic}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}%--posiziona testo in specifiche posizioni
%------------------------------------
\setlength\textwidth{267mm}
\setlength\paperwidth{300mm}
\setlength\oddsidemargin{-1cm}
%-------------------------------
\usepackage{ebgaramond-maths}%----- uso font garamond
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}%----- uso font garamond
%\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[margin=0pt]{geometry}
%\usepackage{showframe} %--show spazi intorno pagina
%------ set colori del link
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=black,
    filecolor=magenta,      
    urlcolor=cyan,
    pdftitle={Overleaf Example},
    pdfpagemode=FullScreen,
    }

 %----- dimensione della pagina ------
 \geometry{
 a3paper,
 total={297mm,420mm},
 left=15mm,
 top=15mm,
 right=15mm,
 bottom=0mm,
 }


\tcbset{colback=white!5!!,colframe=red!15!white!60!,size=small,
fonttitle=\bfseries,width=0.333\textwidth,box align=top,height=7cm,nobeforeafter}

\begin{document}

%----  inserimento banner --------
    \includegraphics [height=40mm,width=267mm]{pannello_blu_corto.png}
    
        \nointerlineskip
       \vspace*{-40mm}  % Tune this to the image height.
\hspace{9cm}
\includegraphics[]{90xngn_new-logo.png}
        
      \noindent\includegraphics[height=10mm,width=267mm]{filo_celeste_basso.png}

%--- riga di testo su banner celeste ----------
%     \vspace{-10,3mm}
%     \hspace{6mm}
%      \textsf{www.nuovogiornalenazionale.com   |   facebook/nuovogiornale \hspace{3cm} \today \hspace{7cm} anno 1   |   numero 1}
  

%------ I linea di box ---------------
\noindent
%\nointerlineskip
   \begin{tcolorbox}[adjusted title=\hyperlink{1_1}{bla bla bla bla},halign=justify]
    \end{tcolorbox} %------fine I box --------
    \begin{tcolorbox}[adjusted title=\hyperlink{1_1}{bla bla bla bla bla ?},halign=justify]
xyz xyz xyz xyz xyz xyz
        \end{tcolorbox}
  \begin{tcolorbox}[adjusted title=\hyperlink{1_1}{xyzxyz xyz xyz xy},halign=justify]
xyz xyz xyz xyz xyz xyz
    \end{tcolorbox}\\
%---------- fine prima linea --------
    \begin{tcolorbox}[adjusted title=left,halign=left]
This is a demonstration text for showing how line breaking works.
\end{tcolorbox}
\begin{tcolorbox}[adjusted title=right,halign upper=right]
This is a demonstration text for showing how line breaking works.
\end{tcolorbox}
\begin{tcolorbox}[adjusted title=right,halign upper=right]
This is a demonstration text for showing how line breaking works.
\end{tcolorbox}\\
\begin{tcolorbox}[adjusted title=right,halign upper=right]
This is a demonstration text for showing how line breaking works.
\end{tcolorbox}
\begin{tcolorbox}[adjusted title=right,halign upper=right]
This is a demonstration text for showing how line breaking works.
\end{tcolorbox}
\begin{tcolorbox}[adjusted title=right,halign upper=right]
This is a demonstration text for showing how line breaking works.
\end{tcolorbox}\\
\begin{tcolorbox}[adjusted title=right,halign upper=right]
This is a demonstration text for showing how line breaking works.
\end{tcolorbox}
\begin{tcolorbox}[adjusted title=right,halign upper=right]
This is a demonstration text for showing how line breaking works.
\end{tcolorbox}
\begin{tcolorbox}[adjusted title=right,halign upper=right]
This is a demonstration text for showing how line breaking works.
\end{tcolorbox}\\
\begin{tcolorbox}[adjusted title=right,halign upper=right]
This is a demonstration text for showing how line breaking works.
\end{tcolorbox}
\begin{tcolorbox}[adjusted title=right,halign upper=right]
This is a demonstration text for showing how line breaking works.
\end{tcolorbox}
\begin{tcolorbox}[adjusted title=right,halign upper=right]
This is a demonstration text for showing how line breaking works.
\end{tcolorbox}
   \newpage
%---- pagina del manifesto -II pag ----------------
\noindent\includegraphics [height=40mm,width=267mm]{bannerLSLC}
%--- riga di testo su banner celeste ----------
%\begin{textblock*}{350mm}(20mm,50mm) % {block width} (coords) 
 %   \textsf{www.nuovogiornalenazionale.com   |   %facebook/nuovogiornale   \hspace{35mm}\today     \hspace{65mm} anno %1   |   numero 1}
%\end{textblock*}
     

      \noindent
     \begin{multicols}{3}
    \noindent
   \centering{
    
    \bfseries {Ibla blbla}}

  \vspace{5mm}
  \justifying
  \noindent
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
\begin{itemize}


    \item text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
```

Comment: Please add a [short, but compilable test file](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) which allows us to reproduce the problem. It should include a class, the necessary packages and a `document` environment.

Comment: sorry samcarter, but I could not send the test file, I just want to understand if that is possible or not.. Not how (I will search it in case a positive answer)

Comment: yes it is possible. How? This will depend on your class etc.

Comment: ok, so exist a class that permit to use a master page.wich one? I'll try to use it and if I will have question about it I will ask to members of this place, posting my problem.

Comment: Most of them. However they don't all use the same mechanism to change the page style and there are also some packages which influence it. You should post a test file which shows us what you have.

Comment: Guess: Read in a LaTeX introduction about the differences of the commands `\pagestyle` and `\thispagestyle`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to change the page style for individual pages. The `article` class is one of the classes where you can do this by using the `\thispagestyle{...}` macro to only change the page style for a single page.

To easily create new page styles, I suggest to use the `fancyhdr` package:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just for this example

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\fancyhead[c]{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=1cm]{example-image-a}}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancypagestyle{special}{%
  \fancyhead[c]{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=1cm]{example-image-duck}}
}

\setlength{\headheight}{1.2cm}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{special}
\lipsum\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: ok, I apologie for the error. Wich class do it?

Comment: @RenatoP Most of them. However they don't all use the same mechanism to change the page style and there are also some packages which influence it. You should post a test file which shows us what you have.